# Yii2 basic app redirect doesn't work

Tags: redirect, yii2

I have made a Yii2 basic app with composer. On localhost (xampp) everything is OK, but when I upload source code on a webhost, redirect codes doesn't work. Even in such a simple action:

```
<?php

namespace app\modules\newsletter\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        echo 'Hi';
        return $this->redirect('http://google.com');
        echo 'Bye';
    }
}
```

It outputs `Hi` and nothing else happens.

Is there any configuration on my web server I can set to fix this?

Comment: try to display php error

Comment: If you do redirect, you shoudn't output anything.

Comment: @NgôVănThao There is no error. error_log is empty and `return $this->redirect()` returns an instance of Response.

Comment: @SiZE Yes but I must go to new page and this don't occur

Comment: Remove the echo, then the redirect should work. As @SIZE already stated. As soon as you start the output, headers can no longer be sent and a redirect is in fact a header (`Location`)

Comment: @Blizz I removed both echos but nothing changed. redirect returns a response object but then nothung happens and I see a white empty page!

Answer (score 0):

The echo statement is probably forcing the headers to be sent before the redirect and therefore the redirect doesn't work. You need to keep all your content within view files. So you would move the echo statement to a view file and either show that view or redirect. You cannot echo out content and redirect in the same request...